# PySpark dataframe to_json() function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like below,

```
>>> df.show(10,False)
+-----+----+---+------+
|id   |name|age|salary|
+-----+----+---+------+
|10001|alex|30 |75000 |
|10002|bob |31 |80000 |
|10003|deb |31 |80000 |
|10004|john|33 |85000 |
|10005|sam |30 |75000 |
+-----+----+---+------+
```

Converting the entire row of df into one new column "jsonCol",

```
>>> newDf1 = df.withColumn("jsonCol", to_json(struct([df[x] for x in df.columns])))
>>> newDf1.show(10,False)
+-----+----+---+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|id   |name|age|salary|jsonCol                                                 |
+-----+----+---+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|10001|alex|30 |75000 |{"id":"10001","name":"alex","age":"30","salary":"75000"}|
|10002|bob |31 |80000 |{"id":"10002","name":"bob","age":"31","salary":"80000"} |
|10003|deb |31 |80000 |{"id":"10003","name":"deb","age":"31","salary":"80000"} |
|10004|john|33 |85000 |{"id":"10004","name":"john","age":"33","salary":"85000"}|
|10005|sam |30 |75000 |{"id":"10005","name":"sam","age":"30","salary":"75000"} |
+-----+----+---+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Instead of converting the entire row into a JSON string like in the above step I needed a solution to select only few columns based on the value of the field. I have provided a sample condition in the below command.

But when I started using the when function, the resultant JSON string's column names(keys) are gone. Only getting column names by their position, instead of the actual column names(keys)

```
>>> newDf2 = df.withColumn("jsonCol", to_json(struct([ when(col(x)!="  ",df[x]).otherwise(None) for x in df.columns])))
>>> newDf2.show(10,False)
+-----+----+---+------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|id   |name|age|salary|jsonCol                                                  |
+-----+----+---+------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|10001|alex|30 |75000 |{"col1":"10001","col2":"alex","col3":"30","col4":"75000"}|
|10002|bob |31 |80000 |{"col1":"10002","col2":"bob","col3":"31","col4":"80000"} |
|10003|deb |31 |80000 |{"col1":"10003","col2":"deb","col3":"31","col4":"80000"} |
|10004|john|33 |85000 |{"col1":"10004","col2":"john","col3":"33","col4":"85000"}|
|10005|sam |30 |75000 |{"col1":"10005","col2":"sam","col3":"30","col4":"75000"} |
+-----+----+---+------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

I needed to use the when function but to have the results as in newDf1 with actual column names(keys). Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have used conditions inside `struct` function as columns and *the condition columns are renamed as col1 col2 ....* and thats why you need `alias` to change the names

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
newDf2 = df.withColumn("jsonCol", F.to_json(F.struct([F.when(F.col(x)!="  ",df[x]).otherwise(None).alias(x) for x in df.columns])))
newDf2.show(truncate=False)
```