# Spark: Dataframe Transformation

Tags: python, json, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have **dataframe_1**:

```
+-------------+----+---------+
|         Name| Age|   Salary|
+-------------+----+---------+
|Avery Bradley|25.0|7730337.0|
|  Jae Crowder|25.0|6796117.0|
+-------------+----+---------+
```

and want to transform it to **dataframe_2**:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|         json_data                                                                                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{"Name": "Avery Bradley", "Age": 25.0, "Salary" 7730337.0}, {"Name": "Jae Crowder", "Age": 25.0, "Salary" 6796117.0}]|    
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I can do `dataframe_1.toPandas().to_dict(orient="records")`, but this would be *dataframe to dict(json object)* transformation and I need *dataframe to dataframe* transformation.

A solution in PySpark, if possible, would be appreciated.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602965/pyspark-dataframe-to-json-function) might help. It uses `to_json()` function.

Comment: Hi @samkart, the answer you mentioned creates json for every row and I need to merge all rows in to a single row, in ```list of json``` format

Comment: use a `collect_list()` post that -- build on the aforementioned, not handing the answers there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `collect_list` of json:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.agg(F.collect_list(F.to_json(F.struct('*'))).alias('json_data'))

df2.show(truncate=False)
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|json_data                                                                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{"Name":"Avery Bradley","Age":25.0,"Salary":7730337.0}, {"Name":"Jae Crowder","Age":25.0,"Salary":6796117.0}]|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge columns to a map then create a JSON out of it

```py
(df
    .withColumn('json', F.to_json(F.create_map(
        F.lit('name'), F.col('name'),
        F.lit('age'), F.col('age'),
        F.lit('salary'), F.col('salary'),
    )))
    .agg(F.collect_list('json').alias('json_value'))
)

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|json_value                                                                                                            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{"name":"Avery Bradley","age":"25.0","salary":"7730337.0"}, {"name":"Jae Crowder","age":"25.0","salary":"6796117.0"}]|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you show me how? According to the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_json.html) the column needs to be StructType or ArrayType or MapType

Comment: @pltc - my apologies, I used a struct similar to mck's answer. [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ssJrAlwdwsq9NV2KxcskpjNMV-J9f6uG) (colab notebook) is the example.