# How to convert some columns to a JSON string (SQL)

Tags: sql, json, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I'm working with Amazon's Glue service and I need to convert some columns to a JSON string. Is this possible with a SQL query (more specifically spark SQL)?

### Example Table

### a | b | c

### 1a  2b  3c

Expected output:

---

### a | json_string

### 1a  '{"b":"2b", "c": "3c"}'

Comment: If using pyspark, why not create a new dataframe column instead of using sql?

Comment: Hello, do you have an example of what you mention?

Comment: Perhaps this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602965/pyspark-dataframe-to-json-function

Comment: `SELECT a, to_json(struct(b, c)) AS json_string FROM my_table`

Comment: @blackbishop Is it possible to do it without specifying which columns? all columns

Comment: You can use list comprehension to create struct from all other columns: `df.select("a", to_json(struct(*[col(c) for c in df.columns if c!="a"])).alias("json_string"))`

Comment: Thank you both very much, both answers helped me.